# Using Protractor how to run multiple spec files without closing browser for each spec file

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm using page object design pattern in my automation tests. I have spec file per page object. When the tests run, browser restarts in between spec files where it asks to login again. But what I'm trying to achieve is that I want to login at the start of the tests, run tests from multiple specs without closing the browser in between executing the spec files.

Comment: I don't think this is good practice, because each test should start with a clean slate and test only one thing. But did you just try to test multiple conditions in one test, e.g. if you are using Jasmine, put multiple expect() in one test?

Comment: thanks atticae. I realized it wasn't a good idea after doing some research. Thanks for the info.

Comment: We run multiple spec files without having to restart the browser, can you post your config file and roughly document your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

In `protractor.conf.js`, under `capabilities`, setting `shardTestFiles: false` will open one browser, run all spec files sequentially in that browser, then exit the browser when all tests have finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Before all" in your first spec file which is needed to load the browser. Once that Spec is run then again next spec is starting to load in same browser window and you won't require login attempt.

```
beforeAll(() => {

browser.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com"),
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

});
```